# Sqoop Export into multiple files

Tags: hive, sqoop

My hive table has close to 1 million records, I want to export these records into csv files such that each of the file will have only 100 records or less.

Please share your thoughts on achieving it using Sqoop.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `--batch` argument in SQOOP export command.
  Please go through this post about [Export more as 10k records with Sqoop](http://mapredit.blogspot.com/2013/11/export-more-as-10k-records-with-sqoop.html) 
Hope this helps.